# How can I prevent interrupt immediately after interruptable step in c-shell script

Tags: csh

C-shell on RHEL6

I want to prevent ^C interrupt from preventing a step in a c-shell script to run.  The catch is that I want the user to be able to use ^C to interrupt the step just before that...

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
# Run the next step, allow ^C interrupt
step1
# I always want to respond to what happened in step1 by running step2
onintr -
step2
onintr
echo "The end"
```

My experiment on this failed.  Apparently multiple, consecutive ^C interrupts for step1 rolled over to the shell and interrupted the shell script before the 'onintr -' could take effect. Again, I can't put the 'onintr -' before step1 because I want the user to be able to interrupt that step.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I can accomplish what I want with a label...

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
# Run the next step, allow ^C interrupt
onintr gohere
step1
# I always want to respond to what happened in step1 by running step2
:gohere
step2
onintr
echo "The end"
```